# Issue changing innodb_log_file_size

Tags: mysql, innodb

I haven't done much tweaking in the past so this might be relatively easy however I am running into issues. This is what I do:

1. Stop MySQL
2. Edit my.cnf (changing `innodb_log_file_size`)
3. Remove ib_logfile0/1
4. Start MySQL

Starts fine however all InnoDB tables have the .frm file is invalid error, the status shows InnoDB engine is disabled so I obviously go back, remove the change and everything works again.

I was able to change every other variable I've tried but I can't seem to find out why InnoDB fails to start even after removing the log files. Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Edit: Pasting of the log below - looks like it still seems to find the log file even though they are not there?

Shutdown:

```
090813 10:00:14  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
090813 10:00:17  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 739268981
090813 10:00:17 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Startup after making the changes:

```
InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 5242880 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 268435456 bytes!
090813 11:00:18 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@XXXXX.com' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
090813 11:00:18 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.0.81-community-log'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Edition (GPL)
090813 11:00:19 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Incorrect information in file: './XXXX/User.frm'
090813 11:00:19 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Incorrect information in file: './XXXX/User.frm'
090813 11:00:19 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Incorrect information in file: './XXXX/User.frm'
```

Its just a spam of the same error until I correct it

When it did start after it recreated the log files so it must be looking in the same spot I am.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, I must point that before any chage in InnoDB data files, one should read [13.2.5. Adding, Removing, or Resizing InnoDB Data and Log Files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-data-log-reconfiguration.html).

The steps you pointed are almost correct. It´s recommended to backup before this types of changes. Lets see what happened to you:

The error messages

> ```
> InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 5242880 bytes
> InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 268435456 bytes!
> ```

are caused by changing the size of innodb_log_file_size and dont deleting the old files. Probably you forgot to delete de `ib_logfile0/1` the first time you ran mysqld after the changing. The message

> ```
> 090813 11:00:18 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
> ```

shows that you resolved this problem (by removing `ib_logfile`s). But, on removing them you create the other problem. Data corrupt for XXXX\User.frm or some problem with InnoDB Engine.

To be sure that InnoDB is enabled, run this command on a mysql prompt:

```
show variables like "%inno%";
```

In the result list must have "`have_innodb = YES`". Sometimes when InnoDB can **not** start (value is `NO` or `DISABLED`) the `Incorrect information in file` message appears.
- If this is the problem, you have changed something else that prevents InnoDB Engine to start properly (datadir´s permissions or tmpdir´s permissions, other innodb variables (*you didnt show the complete log.*), etc.). Review the changes or put the `.cnf` files (before and after).
- If the InnoDB Engine is `YES` then you have to repair the table. *(If it´s this case, add a comment and I´ll add the information here. I´m too lazy to do it now.)*

Comment: I recommend full shutdown so first `SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

The first line in the error suggests you haven't deleted the ib_logfile0. Can you confirm you're renaming / deleting the right one?

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

- Is there enough space on the device to create the log file of that size? This behavior may be coming from a full device.
- Are the log files being created with the wrong settings?
- Your path to the logfile doesn't show as absolute. Just for grins, see if there are any other locations on your drive that contain an ib_logfile0. Might be a silly bug.

Comment: There is enough space. (about 250 g free)

The log files are not created at all, after I run the startup they don't exist anywhere.

Did a find for ib_logfile* on the root and it came back with the only location I removed them from.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an SQL Client to edit the `innodb_log_file_size` field?

Personally I like [SQuirreL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: innodb related fields cannot be edited from within the client.  they have to be edited in my.cnf, and are taken as the new values upon service restart.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you removed the wrong log files. look around for other ib_logfile* files. maybe you are using innodb_log_group_home_dir ?

if so, make sure that you removed the ib_logfiles from there and not the datadir.