# can't resize innodb_log_file_size in my.cnf

Tags: mysql, sql, database, innodb

I have a mysql 5.0 sonar database that is bloated (360gb instead of on average 30gb)

This link said in order to fix it I need to export the DB, install mysql 5.6, import and export, and it should go back to its original size..: [SonarQube : How to reduce size of measures_data.ibd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873974/sonarqube-how-to-reduce-size-of-measures-data-ibd)

So we got a virtual machine to test, installed  Centos 5.6 , and mysql 5.6, and started the import...
Unfortunately it I always get errors in some of the imports...

> [ERROR] InnoDB: The total blob data length (39220742) is greater than
> 10% of the redo log file size (3072). Please increase
> innodb_log_file_size.

which brought me to the many links of innodb_log_file_size like this one:
[Issue changing innodb_log_file_size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273012/issue-changing-innodb-log-file-size)

I shut down mysql without errors.
I modify my.cnf

> innodb_log_file_size=64M    (for example purposes although I tried much higher values as well to try like 600M 6G etc..)

I deleted the ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 logs in /var/lib/mysql  then restarted the service
, but nothing changes.. (Even though from what i read that shouldnt matter in 5.6)

> 2014-10-09 13:05:09 18205 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>
> 2014-10-09 13:05:10 18205 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile101 size to 48 MB
>
> 2014-10-09 13:05:10 18205 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile1 size to 48 MB
>
> 2014-10-09 13:05:10 18205 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file ./ib_logfile101 to ./ib_logfile0
>
> 2014-10-09 13:05:10 18205 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=36443469334

I truncated all the table data after a failed import and altered each of them to be  compressed with key_block_size 8k. I also removed all the "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" from the backup i'm importing from  so that I could keep the tables compressed, that didn't work either...

> active_rule_changes       | InnoDB |      10 | Compressed |      379 |             86 |       32768 >|               0 |         8192 |         0 |            566 | 2014-10-08 18:03:45 | NULL        | >NULL       | utf8_bin  |     NULL | row_format=COMPRESSED KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=8 |         |

I'm not sure what to do... my log doesnt get an error, and from what I read, this should be straightforward.

Heres the my.cnf file for the data import.

> innodb_file_per_table = 1
>
> innodb_file_format = Barracuda
>
> innodb_file_format_max = Barracuda
>
> innodb_file_format_check = ON

Ideas would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You're probably more likely to get a good answer about this on superuser.com or dba.stackexchange.com as this question doesn't have to do with programming.

Comment: Thanks! I'll post over there.

Comment: Please don't cross-post (unless you delete this question). We can move the question there automatically if we vote for it. I just voted to move to dba.stackexchange.com, we just need two more votes. Give it a few minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common problem people experience is that they have more than one line in /etc/my.cnf defining a variable. The *last* line defining the variable in the file wins. So search your config file for another line that sets the log file size back to 48M.

Another possibility is that you put the variable definition in the wrong group. It belongs under the `[mysqld]` group in the config file.

FWIW, you don't need to export and import all your data, unless you need to shrink the `ibdata1` tablespace.

You can compact any individual `.ibd` file by using `OPTIMIZE TABLE`.

Comment: I knew it was something stupid. I had the value under [innodb] Thanks!

Comment: I don't think `[innodb]` is a real group that is recognized in the my.cnf. MySQL will silently ignore option groups that it doesn't recognize.

Comment: https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001738733-How-to-change-the-innodb-log-file-size-value-in-MySQL-MariaDB